# Can I replace this filtering network with a saw filter chip?

Tags: rf, microwave

[image: A7105 application circuit]

The above image is the Application Circuit from the A7105 radio transciever chip's data sheet.

I think I am beginning to understand the purpose of most of these components.

I suspect that the circled components are working as a band-pass filter (or at least, a high-pass filter) for the module's frequency, which is 2.4 ghz.

I have not yet tried to build this circuit, as it is rather complicated and requires a lot of tiny smd components (on a custom board). So far I have only worked with already made modules which use this chip.

My question is:

If I replace the circled components with a SMD "Saw Filter" component, as a band-pass filter for the 2.4 ghz ISM band, is it likely to work? Assume that I also provide a suitable antenna, either a chip or pcb antenna.

Comment: The circled components are unambiguous technically. An SMD saw filter can mean anything and more than likely you'll pick one that is inappropriate so **no** you can't, given that you haven't specified one and/or done some simulations to demonstrate equality.

Comment: Also consider that C6, C10, L3, C12, and REG0A can influence behavior. These cannot be ignored at 2.4GHz.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to share this diagram that says CONFIDENTIAL?

Comment: @user253751 It is in no way confidential, you can find that datasheet all over the internet and the chip was made generally available many years ago. The company never updated the datasheet after GA I guess (if they did, I don't have an updated version).